# How to get LINQ to Autoformat in Visual Studio appropriately?

Tags: linq, autoformatting

I am trying to get LINQ queries to autoformat nicely, but they are "outdenting" some queries, which looks ugly and confusing.  How do I get LINQ queries to format appropriately?

Here's the [offending formatting](https://github.com/tarr11/linq-formatting/blob/master/linq-formatting/Program.cs)

[Repro CSProj](https://github.com/tarr11/linq-formatting) (this is VS 2013 but it also happens in 2012)

My autoformatting options are defaults :
[image: AutoFormatting Part 1]
[image: Part 2]
[image: Part 3]
[image: Part 4]

Comment: I opened the same project, but when I fixed it and then autoformatted nothing changed (it didn't revert to the outdenting). Is that what it's doing for you?

Comment: Yeah, once you manually fix it, it stays (usually). I'd like for it to autoformat correctly without manually doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it appears out that Visual Studio will not autoformat LINQ queries, most of the time.  There are a few occasions where it appears that VS autoformatting makes things *worse*, but you can avoid those by using these steps.

However, if you use the correct keypresses when building queries, you can have it manually format correctly, and Visual Studio will NOT reformat it.

I've automated this using a [vsvim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) macro, but it will work with any environment.

### Poorly Formatted LINQ

[image: Poorly Formatted LINQ]

### Step 1: Pull the second line up

[image: Step 1]

### Step 2: Type "Enter" at the correct element to reformat correctly

[image: Step 2]

### Step 3: Repeat as necessary for remainder of the query

[image: Step 3]